# Entity Framework - Only update values that are not null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This is a bit of a new one for me.  I've been asked to write an ETL program that loads two datasets into the same table.  Dataset #1 is complete and contains all the data for the table.  Dataset#2, however, only contains *changes* that need to be overlaid onto the first dataset.  Observe:

// Dataset #1: Widgets Table

```
+----+------+------+------+------+
| ID | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
| 1  | abcd | abcd | abcd | abcd |
+----+------+------+------+------+
| 2  | abcd | abcd | abcd | abcd |
+----+------+------+------+------+
```

// Dataset #2: Widgets_Changes Table

```
+----+------+------+------+------+
| ID | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
| 1  |      | efgh |      | ijkl |
+----+------+------+------+------+
| 2  | mnop |      | qrst |      |
+----+------+------+------+------+
```

// The Anticipated Result: Widgets with all Changes

```
+----+------+------+------+------+
| ID | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
| 1  | abcd | efgj | abcd | ijkl |
+----+------+------+------+------+
| 2  | mnop | abcd | qrst | abcd |
+----+------+------+------+------+
```

The obvious approach (that I'm trying to avoid) is to pull each widget out of the first table and do a property-by-property comparison:

```
// Simplified example:
using ( var db = new MyEntityDatabase() ){

   var widget      = from p in db.Widgets select p where p.ID == 1;
   var widget_diff = from p in db.Widgets_Changes select p where p.ID == 1

   widget.COL1 = widget_diff.COL1 ?? widget.COL1;
   widget.COL2 = widget_diff.COL2 ?? widget.COL2;
   widget.COL3 = widget_diff.COL3 ?? widget.COL3;
   // ...etc

   db.saveChanges();
}
```

However, there are over 200 fields in this particular dataset, with more files incoming that adhere to this same methodology (complete dataset accompanied by diff dataset) but have a different schema entirely.

I'd like to find a solution that avoids hard-coding property-by-property comparisons for each dataset, but not sure how.  Is there a way to iterate through the properties of both objects and update values that aren't null?

Comment: You could use reflection to do that, use PropertyInfo to get the properties

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, you need to use something like this to select the entities you want to update:

```
var widget      = db.Widgets.First(p => p.ID == 1);
var widget_diff = db.Widgets_Changes.First(p => p.ID == 1);
```

Now you can simply use reflection to update all fields:

```
foreach(var toProp in typepf(Widget).GetProperties())
{
    var fromProp= typeof(Widget_Change).GetProperty(toProp.Name);
    var toValue = fromProp.GetValue(widget_diff, null);
    if (toValue != null)
    {
        toProp.SetValue(widget, toValue, null);
    }
}
```

This can be sped up a bit by building a list the of properties up front, so you only have to use reflection once:

```
public static class WidgetUtil
{
    public static readonly IEnumerable<Tuple<PropertyInfo, PropertyInfo>> PropertyMap;

    static Util()
    {
        var b = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        PropertyMap = 
            (from f in typeof(Widget).GetProperties(b)
             join t in typeof(WidgetChange).GetProperties(b) on f.Name equals t.Name
             select Tuple.Create(f, t))
            .ToArray();
    }
}

...

foreach(var propertyPair in WidgetUtil.PropertyMap)
{
    var toValue = propertyPair.Item2.GetValue(widget_diff, null);
    if (toValue != null)
    {
        propertyPair.Item1.SetValue(widget, toValue, null);
    }
}
```

If you have many such entity types, you might even want to consider making this into a generic utility:

```
public static class WidgetUtil<T1, T2>
{
    public static readonly IEnumerable<Tuple<PropertyInfo, PropertyInfo>> PropertyMap;

    static WidgetUtil()
    {
        var b = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        PropertyMap = 
            (from f in typeof(T1).GetProperties(b)
             join t in typeof(T2).GetProperties(b) on f.Name equals t.Name
             select Tuple.Create(f, t))
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: My goodness.  This is so much better than anything I could have hoped for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You might want to use reflection for this.  Loop through all of the properties/fields for each widget/difference, get the value of that property/field, if the difference is null, then use the original value.

```
using(var db = new MyEntityDatabase())
{
    var widget      = from p in db.Widgets select p where p.ID == 1;
    var widget_diff = from p in db.Widgets_Changes select p where p.ID == 1;

    var properties = typeof(MyWidgetType).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach(var property in properties)
    {
         //widget.column = widget_diff.column ?? widget.colum;
         property.SetValue(property.GetValue(widget_diff) ?? property.GetValue(widget), widget);
    }

    //You can do the same for fields here if the entity has any fields (probably not).
}
```

Comment: Note that if `widget` and `widget_diff` are of different types, this won't work. You'll need to use the appropriate `PropertyInfo` for each object.

Answer (score 3):

@p.s.w.g's answer is great, however when I tried to implement it I encountered several bugs (such as for example you can't check for null with obj.Equals(null), null doesn't have Equals method).

Here is a "complete copy-pastable solution" of @p.s.w.g's great answer (as a by-product)

A static generic method `InjectNonNull` gets the source entity you want to update and the destination "sparce" entity with nulls, and transfers only the non-null properties on destination entity.

```
    private static class PropertyLister<T1, T2>
    {
        public static readonly IEnumerable<Tuple<PropertyInfo, PropertyInfo>> PropertyMap;

        static PropertyLister()
        {
            var b = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
            PropertyMap =
                (from f in typeof(T1).GetProperties(b)
                 join t in typeof(T2).GetProperties(b) on f.Name equals t.Name
                 select Tuple.Create(f, t))
                    .ToArray();
        }
    }


    public static T InjectNonNull<T>(T dest, T src)
    {
        foreach (var propertyPair in PropertyLister<T, T>.PropertyMap)
        {
            var fromValue = propertyPair.Item2.GetValue(src, null);
            if (fromValue != null && propertyPair.Item1.CanWrite)
            {

                propertyPair.Item1.SetValue(dest, fromValue, null);
            }
        }

        return dest;
    }
```

Comment: +1 Yes, I actually saw that issue a little while back. `toValue.Equals(null)` should be `toValue != null` or `Object.Equals(toValue, null)`. I've corrected my answer for completeness, but I adding the `propertyPair.Item1.CanWrite` is a good idea, too.