# T entity type conversion and removing nulls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using .net core 7. I am sending a json as below. The json object I sent can always change. For example, when I don't submit the "Description" field, it changes to "null" in the database.

```
{
  "id": 105,
  "name": "Test1"
}
```

In the json object I sent, when there is no "description", it marks it as null and replaces it in the database.
`Company` table:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

`CompanyUpdateDTO`:

```
public class CompanyUpdateDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I am sending it as an entity through the controller:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] CompanyUpdateDto updateCompany)
{
    await _service.UpdateAsync(_mapper.Map<Company>(updateCompany));
    return CreateActionResult(CustomResponseDto<CompanyUpdateDto>.Success(204));
}
```

I want to remove columns with `null` field in incoming json object. I did this as follows, but I could not convert it back to the entity structure. Can we remove the `null` values in this field and convert them back to entity?

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
{
    //JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
    //{
    //    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
    //};
    //T serialized = (T)Convert.ChangeType(JsonSerializer.Serialize(entity, options), typeof(T));
    //Console.WriteLine(serialized);

    //var sonuc2 = (T)Convert.ChangeType(serialized, typeof(T));


    _repository.Update(entity);
    await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hello. Even removing the null values from the json object, when you convert it to the entity class, the properties not set would have the default values, that is `null` in case of nullable properties.
I think you shouldn't `Update` the whole entity of the database, but only the fields that aren't null.

Comment: yes you are right, but how can I update only certain fields?

Comment: What is `_repository`, the DbContext? Are you using EF Core?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework - Only update values that are not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385472/entity-framework-only-update-values-that-are-not-null)

Comment: NULL? or "NULL" string?

Comment: I am using efcore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the Company with id,and then replace the name of the Company,here is a demo of efcore:

```
var Company= await _context.Companys.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == updateCompany.Id);//you can get the company by id with your code
Company.Name=updateCompany.Name;
await _service.UpdateAsync(_mapper.Map<Company>(Company));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try as below to Update part of the entity for simple types:

```
foreach (var prop in company.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (prop.GetValue(company).ToString().Contains("Some") || prop.Name=="Id")
                {
                   _context.Entry(company).Property(prop.Name).IsModified = false;
                }
                else{
                    _context.Entry(company).Property(prop.Name).IsModified = true;

                }  

            }
           

            try
            {
                
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```

The result:

Comment: not that way, i need to do this globally. Because there is more than one table